# HTML forms multi-select using GET

Tags: php, html, forms

**NOTE :**

It's sort of hard to google for this, because "GET" is bringing up a lot of "how to 'get' the value of a form with javascript," etc.

**PROBLEM :**

*TL;DR version first*

**Can you use a multi-select from with the GET method of a form and still retrieve each individual value?**

*extended explanation*

The requirements of a searchable catalog I'm building include using the GET method with the form, so that the user can see their results in the url, and also send a direct link to the search results to another customer, etc.

One of the searchable fields is a multi-select box (a select box with the `MULTIPLE` attribute).  My back end is written in PHP, and I usually handle a multi-select by setting the name to an array variable `(name="multiselect[]")` and the post variable includes an array of the selected options `($_POST["multiselect"] == array())`.

The problem in this case is that the multi-select values are passed to the get string like this:

```
action?multiselect=1&multiselect=2
```

So whatever the last value is replaces the value of the first initialization of the variable in the get string. (in the above example, multiselect would equal "2").

Trying to make the name an array just makes the array value replaced in the same manner, like this

```
action?multiselect[]=1&multiselect[]=2
```

Will result in `$_GET["multiselect"] == 2`

I had originally recommended using a checkbox, as it would allow us to name the elements differently and check for true/false on each one, but there are around 30 values for this particular multi-select, and they want it to be in a scroll-able area.

Comment: Why not just add hidden form elements and copy the multiselect value to the appropriate checkbox.  Easy to do with jquery.  You obviously have a reason for the "Get" use but remember URLS have a finite length to them.  You cant go sending 8K of data across the URL itself.

Comment: have you tried using a foreach loop to go through the post variables or useing size of $_GET["multiselect"]?

Comment: That's a good point. It might be a good idea to limit the subset of options they have available to them in any case.
Originally I was trying to keep this form fully degradeable (not that I really expect to cater to people who have JS turned off, but if someone's JS fails or anything, we're always covered).
Are my hands just tied by the way browsers send form data via GET?

Comment: Well barryhunter proved I was having another issue. But now that I think about it Mech, it's still sending a blank value for every input on the form. Is there a way outside of JS to keep that from happening to limit the url size? (this seems like it needs to be a new question now)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Works for me. Just tried

http://www.nearby.org.uk/tmp/multi-test.html

```
<select name="multiselect[]" ...
```

Results in a URL
?multiselect%5B%5D=2&multiselect%5B%5D=3

which will make $_GET['multiselect'] an array in PHP.

Perhaps you have something else in your system, stripping the [] ?

Comment: It's weird, because when I tried that originally the "multiselect" didn't escape the [] into %5B and %5D, it just left them like they were ([]) which the server apparently didn't understand.

Now that I'm trying it, it's showing what you're talking about, so let me see if I had some other underlying issue.

Comment: @NateDSaint, is it possible you were debugging a cached version of the page that didn't update the `[name]`?

Comment: Epic fail on my part. Apparently one of my javascript libraries was unescaping everything before it sent to the server. I was testing with no JS turned on, and it just worked. Leaving the question up so everyone can get rep and someone else can find this since I was beating my head against a wall trying to google it.

Comment: @zzzzBov that was actually part of the problem too, kept me from noticing what I was doing because I was refreshing the same url instead of hitting submit and seeing the browser generate a new one