# read multiple values from select option html

Tags: php, html, select

I am creating a select tag as --

```
<select name="payments[0][countries][]" class="input-medium select2 correct-wide payment-country" multiple data-placeholder="All">
  <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
  <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
  <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
  <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
  <option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option>
  <option value="AO">Angola</option>
  <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
  <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
  <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
</select>
```

Where the user can select multiple values and submit the details, in my php page i am reading the values as --

```
$pc = $_POST["payments[0][countries]"];
$limit7 = count($pc);
for($i=0;$i<$limit7;$i++) 
{
    $pcv .= $pc[$i]."~";
}
```

But I am getting the following error

> Notice: Undefined index: payments[0][countries] in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\trackingtool\admin-add-offer2.php on line 271
>
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\trackingtool\admin-add-offer2.php on line 272

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML forms multi-select using GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015088/html-forms-multi-select-using-get)

Comment: You know that if you just Google your question, you will find tons of material about it? Even here in StackOverflow (like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957588/store-multiple-select-option-into-a-php-array)

Comment: Use _$_POST["payments"]_. And before asking please search on Google or SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your PHP to this

```
foreach ($_POST['payments'][0]['countries'] as $pc) {
  $pcv .= $pc."~";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you are accessing it the wrong way

make it `$_POST['payments'][0]['countries']`;

`payment` is the index name but payment is also an array and on the 0th index has countries column which is also is an array. So think about it.